# Webpack ESM import file extension error inconsistency

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, webpack-5

I have a Webpack 5 project using an npm package composed of multiple ES files using imports that don't end with a (`.js`) file extension. For context, these files are the result of the 'tsc' typescript compiler and the file extension can only be added by modifying the original typescript source code which I'm trying to avoid.

```
// node_modules/my-package/dist/index.js
export { Button } from "./button";

// src/app.ts
import { Button } from "my-package";

// node_modules/my_package/package.json
...
"module": "./dist/index.js"
...
```

The build process finishes fine in this case. However if the above `package.json` is modified to include the following line:

```
// node_modules/my-package/package.json
...
"module": "./dist/index.js",
"type": "module"
...
```

Webpack returns the following error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './button' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is a '*.mjs' file or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

How come webpack only requires file extensions in ESM-style imports if `"type": "module"` is set? Why is the above error not raised if that line is omitted from `package.json`?

I'm assuming webpack correctly detects that the code is ESM in both cases, so I would expect the same (consistent) behavior. Can the fact that in the first case no error is thrown be relied on?